# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received when i tried to get collision detection

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I stuck at this position and don't know what went wrong in this,

I have enabled ARC in my project. And i made softBody as follows

**Ball.h**

```
    B2Body *body[NUM_SEGMENT];
    CCSprite *ball;
```

**Ball.mm**

```
    ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Ball1.2.png"];
    ball.tag = 1;


    for(int i=0;i<NUM_SEGMENT;i++){
        float theta = deltaAngle*i;
        float x = radius * cosf(theta);
        float y = radius * sinf(theta);
        b2Vec2 circlePosition = b2Vec2(x/PTM_RATIO,y/PTM_RATIO);
        b2BodyDef bodyDef;
        bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position = (center + circlePosition);
        bodyDef.userData = &ball;
        body[i] = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
        outerBodyFixture[i]=body[i]->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
        [bodies addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:body[i]]];
    }
```

And I have given physics to the tiles as follows,

**Tile.h**

```
CCSprite *tile;
```

**Tile.mm**

```
tile = [layer1 tileAt:ccp(i, j)];
tile.tag = 0;
b2BodyDef tileDef;
tileDef.type = b2_staticBody;
tileDef.position.Set((tile.position.x+(tile.contentSize.width/2))/(PTM_RATIO), (tile.position.y + (tile.contentSize.height/2))/PTM_RATIO);
tileDef.userData = &tile;
tileBody = world->CreateBody(&tileDef);
```

Now i tried to catch collision detection and I have made code which will print the tag number of colliding bodies. The code is as follows,

```
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
    for (pos=_contactListener->_contacts.begin();
         pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
        MyContact contact = *pos;

        b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
        if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
```

**At this point Getting ERROR: EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

```
        CCSprite *spriteA = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
```

**At this point Getting ERROR: EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

```
        CCSprite *spriteB = (__bridge CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();


            printf("contact :%d \n",spriteB.tag);
        }
    }
```

Don't Know whats wrong with this code,,Give me some solution for this

Comment: bad idea to use tile sprites, from what I remember cocos2d creates the tile sprites dynamically and may recreate or release them.

Comment: actually i want to add physics to some specific sprite..that's why i used tilesprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you store in `userData` a pointer to a pointer rather than the pointer itself.

`tile` is already pointing to a `CCSprite` instance and `&tile` points to a pointer to a `CCSprite` instance making your casting incorrect.

So change it to :

```
tileDef.userData = tile;
```